# Clustering a set of curves

Tags: clustering, k-means, distance, curve-fitting, similarities

I am working with a MRI dataset where we inject dye into a person's wrist and measure intensity per time on a voxel-by-voxel basis. I am trying to determine if it is possible to identify certain tissues based upon their curve similarity (they have unique looking intensity curves).

[image: one example curve]

I am using Euclidean distance k-means in order to try this. The data seems to be OK, but I need a way to determine uniformity between curves—how similar curves in a group are to one another. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Can you provide some example data? What are the "curves" in this context? Are they some kind of densities over values (eg, histograms)? Are they curvilinear relationships b/t 2 different variables?

Comment: It is intensity over time. So, for a specific voxel, I would have one intensity value per one time point.

Comment: Here is an example of what a curve might look like. [link](https://s2.postimg.org/pb3vk2ybd/Sample_Curve.png)

Comment: How many curves do you have? Are you trying to cluster (unsupervised) or build a classification model that correctly identifies labeled and unlabeled cases?

Comment: What is important for you in measuring similarity of curves? only the values? derivatives? Something else? This curves can be seen as functions, so some possibilities are: $L_1$, $L_2$, or using derivatives some [Sobolev space distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Sobolev_spaces)